# Hibernate import.sql not found wherever I put it

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat, jpa

I'm using a Spring MVC + JPA/Hibernate config over maven.
When I deploy to Tomcat I expect Hibernate to execute an import.sql file but it doesn't matter where I put it or how I configure the path to the file, it never finds it.

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport SchemaExport - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport SchemaExport - Import file not found: /META-INF/import.sql
```

My configuration for Hibernate is, in Spring:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/META-INF/import.sql</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm using a standard Maven web folder structure, putting my `import.sql` in the `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`folder. I also tried removing the `import_files` property and putting it in the `webapp` folder to no avail.

I suspect it can be something related to the tomcat policy of mapping `web.jar` urls against `server_root/web/*`.

Comment: Put it in `src/main/resources` instead of  `webapp`.

Comment: Great, thanks, please post it as a solution so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `import.sql` is read from the root of the classpath. In a maven project `src/main/webapp` isn't the classpath but the web content. The classpath consists of the java classes in `src/main/java` and additonal non java things in `src/main/resources`.

Putting your `import.sql` into the `src/main/resources` will let hibernate load it. As when constructing the jar the content of this directory is copied to `WEB-INF/classes` which in a web application is part of the classpath.

Comment: Attention: Put every command to a separate line and do not split an SQL among 2 or more lines! Then `import.sql` works (with H2 in-memory database).

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to change that location, you may set this property

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files
```

Default is

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/import.sql"
```

To load multiple sql files, just separate them whith comma, like

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/scripts/business.sql,/scripts/security.sql"
```

Regards!