# How to specify a relative file path in a standard Maven project

Tags: java, maven

My Maven project needs to load data to database, and the `import.sql` contains the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
`'/home/jack/ubuntu/bword/src/main/resources/Term.txt' INTO TABLE Term FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id,name);`
```

The path used here is the absolute path on my machine. How can I specify a relative path to make it work? I tried these:

```
/bword/src/main/resources/Term.txt
../bword/src/main/resources/Term.txt
../bword/src/main/resources/Term.txt
../src/main/resources/Term.txt
```

None of these work. The file is located at `src/main/resources`, a default directory in a Maven directory.

I am using JBoss and hibernate, JPA.

Comment: What is consuming this file? a maven plugin (which one?) a Java main? a test?

Comment: Actually, I don't know exactly. I think it's consumed by Java Persistence API and Hibernate, since I am using these APIs to access mysql database. By convention, import.sql will be executed automatically when the web app is started, and Hibernate will create the database and populate the data.

Comment: Ok, then the file will be used by your application, not by Maven, there would be no notion of `src/main/resources`, you can remove it, try simply with `/Term.txt` then (means: at the root of the classpath)

Comment: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Term.txt' INTO TABLE Term FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id,name). Could not send file : /Term.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: and what about simply `Term.txt`? (I don't like this try-game, but with the given information it is always worth giving a try)

Comment: Sorry. No luck, the same message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106284/discussion-between-user697911-and-a-di-matteo).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can't do it.

Your application is web application (*I take a look on chat*). Maven can package `import.sql` and `Term.txt` into the application. Both files are visible on classpath. Hibernate scans classpath, finds `import.sql` and execute it.

But when `import.sql` is proceed,  the command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_name' ...
```

is executed. `'file_name'` is resolved against current working dir.

1. Is `Term.txt` visible in filesystem? I don't think so.
2. Does you application control current directory of JBoss process? No

Summary:

1. `Term.txt` is not visible as file on JBoss filesystem
2. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE needs file on JBoss filesystem

Comment: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE needs file on JBoss filesystem", is it possible to do this?

Comment: Isn't this a common scenario, or it's rare that people load data to database by Hibernate this way?

Comment: Main purpose of Hibernate is provide JPA mapping. `import.sql` is add-on - useful but not core feature. Load a database is not trivial case due indempotency. Flywaydb is one of tools to populate database. Other, simple solution is transform `Term.txt` into many sql insert commands, write them to file and execute the file by Hibernate (hibernate can load many files at startup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27709692/2365727)